# Filter Tables from Another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a problem with create query

```
===========      ============================         ================= 
ValueTable1      ValueTable2                          FilterTable1      
===========      ============================         ================= 
Id |Name         Id | RefNo || Property| Value        Id|Property|Operator|Value
 1 |X             1     1       P1         500         1   P1        >       100
                  2     1       P2         300         1   P2        =       300
                  3     1       P3         200         1   P3        <>      100

2  |Y             4     2       P1         250
                  5     2       P2         100
                  6     2       P3         200
```

I have 2 table ValueTable and 1 filter table in my database
I wanna create a query that can filter Valuetabl2 from properties and operators in FilterTable1
I couldnt create it.Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I did misunderstood your question...

You want do apply those Filters on FilterTable1 on the values of table ValueTable2, right?

doing AND condition... with the filters..

to identify what RefNo fill all conditions.. I am right? or did misunderstood at this point?

and this RefNo references the table ValueTable1, right? or I did misunderstood??

if I did undestood right

can try something like this...

```
    create table ##ValueTable1 (id int , name varchar)
    insert into ##ValueTable1
    values (1,'X'),(2,'Y')

    create table ##ValueTable2 (id int , RefNo int, Property nvarchar(max),value int)
    insert into ##ValueTable2
    values 
    ( 1 ,   1  ,'P1',      500),
    ( 2 ,   1  ,'P2',      300),
    ( 3 ,   1  ,'P3',      200),
    ( 4 ,   2  ,'P1',      250),
    ( 5 ,   2  ,'P2',      100),
    ( 6 ,   2  ,'P3',      200)

    create table ##FilterTable1 (id int, Property nvarchar(max),Operator nvarchar(max) , value int)
    insert into ##FilterTable1
    values 
    (1,'P1','>', 100),
    (1,'P2','=', 300),
    (1,'P3','<>',100)




     declare @sql nvarchar(max)
     set @sql = ''
     select @sql = @sql + ' intersect  select RefNo from ##ValueTable2 where Property = ''' +Property+''' and value '+Operator+CAST(value as varchar(max))
     from ##FilterTable1 
     where id = 1
     set @sql = 'select * from ##ValueTable1 T inner join ('+STUFF(@sql,1,10,'') +')V on V.RefNo = T.id'
     --just stuff @sql if ##ValueTable1 doesnt matter
     --set @sql = STUFF(@sql,1,10,'')  

     exec(@sql)


    drop table ##ValueTable2
    drop table ##FilterTable1
    drop table ##ValueTable1
```

my resultset achieved is...

```
id  name    RefNo
1   X       1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a string for your sql statement in a procedure loop for example and then execute it.

See here how to execute it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188332.aspx.

You can not create dynamic sql queries directly.

So create a procedure, create a local cursor to loop to your `ValueTable2` and for each property check the `operator` in `FilterTable1`, then create a new sql string which you execute then.

*EDIT*

I don't fully understand your requirement, but this example should give you an approach:

```
DECLARE @operator varchar(2)
DECLARE @value varchar(255)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR

SELECT [operator], CAST([value] AS varchar(255))
FROM ValueTable2 v
JOIN FilterTable1 f ON v.Property = f.Property

OPEN cur1

FETCH NEXT FROM cur1
INTO @operator, @value

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
  @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ValueTable2 WHERE [value] ' + @operator + ' ' + @value
  PRINT @sql
  -- EXEC sp_executesql @sql
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @operator, @value
END

DEALLOCATE cur1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to execute it but I couldnt create query.Filter Table Rows have to be AND Clause when

Comment: 2nd edit: @value need to be varchar, so I CAST() the value

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would try NOT to use CURSORS and/or Dynamic SQL. Cursors are possible of creating serious locking issues, and dynamic SQL is always being (re)compiled, so doing that together is a no go in my point of view.

However, using a temp table with a while loop might be better in stead of cursors. For logic i would say it must be possible to use some if statements..

I made this SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a4e3/) to show you what i mean